# C++ CreateWindow: button position gets offset at window maximize

Tags: c++, winapi, coordinates, offset, createwindow

I have a weird problem over here. I created a DLL proxy for Spotify so I can "overlay" a button onto it. Basicially, thats how it works:

```
DllMain
  -> Creates CMain class
    -> Creates CToggleButton class
      -> Hooks the button onto the Spotify window
```

It has two methods, one static one which I use for the thread since threads can't call member functions, and one non-static function which gets called by the member function.
With this, I create the thread and pass an instance of the CToggleButton class via lpParam:

```
CreateThread(0, NULL, WindowThreadStatic, (void*)this, NULL, NULL);
```

Then, the WindowThreadStatic function:

```
DWORD WINAPI CToggleButton::WindowThreadStatic(void* lpParam)
{
   return ((CToggleButton*)lpParam)->WindowThread();
}
```

And the main window thread function inside the class:

```
DWORD CToggleButton::WindowThread()
{
MSG msg;
hButton = CreateWindowA("BUTTON", "Test", (WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD), 0, 0, 100, 20, parenthWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);

bool bQueueRunning = true;
while (bQueueRunning)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, parenthWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        switch (msg.message)
        {
        case WM_QUIT:
            bQueueRunning = false;
            break;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            if (msg.hwnd == hButton)
            {
                MessageBoxA(parenthWnd, "Button!", "Button", MB_OK);
                continue;
            }
        }

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    Sleep(10);
}

return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this also contains the message loop for the button (I didn't use GetMessage() here because it was very unresponsive so I decided to use PeekMessage() together with a 10ms delay, which works fine.)
Little picture to show how it looks like:
[image]

All great, but if I maximize the window, the button disappears. When I minimize and maximize the window a few times, the button can be seen again, but with very weird coordinates (not the original 0,0 I gave him).
[image]
So what is my problem here? Why do the coordinates get offset?
Thanks for reading my long post :)

Comment: Spotify is probably playing with the position of the client area or something like that. That being said, creating a cross-thread parent-child hierarchy is a risky thing to do. [Starting point for further reading.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: Yeah, little chance of making this robust like that

Comment: Doing all of that inside DllMain is very bad practice, if that's really what you're doing.

Comment: @JonathanPotter It's running in a different thread..

Comment: @andlabs Could I just remove and create the button again at 0,0? That way I'd only need to catch an event if the window maximizes, if thats possible..

Comment: Running in a different thread doesn't make running it from DllMain() any safer, because the act of creating a thread in DllMain() is still unsafe. ([Starting point for further reading.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283)) I genuinely do not know what the best approach for this problem is, sorry...